# Capture USER_ID For Delete Operation

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

We currently use Auditing triggers to track all of our DB changes.  In order to capture the user_id for the person that submitted the delete we have to use an update and then have the trigger perform a delete so we can capture that USER_ID.

Does anyone else use a different approach or have a better approach for this process?

Thanks,

--S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a direct connection from the client, use SUSER_SNAME() or similar in the DELETE trigger.

For an indirect (eg via a web site), use [SET CONTEXT_INFO (answers by me before)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A27535+%22SET+CONTEXT_INFO+%22) to pass in the executing user details. This can be set via code in the web site or via stored proc parameters. This can also be used for a direct connection too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Authentication (either 2-tier, or impersonation) then you can use [SUSER_NAME()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) and [SUSER_ID()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176042.aspx)

```
select SUSER_NAME(), USER_ID()
```